# Storing input as different types in Java

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am looking for a way to retrieve user input. I found two solutions; one uses `Scanner`, and the other one uses `BufferedReader`.
And I have noticed that `BufferedReader` only returns `String`.

I am looking for a way to safely retrieve information from user input.

In the below example, I want to store Cname as `String` and Grade and Weight as `float`.
Any suggestions on how to best achieve that as their type? I know there are couple of ways such as stringToInt or nextInt or even writing some validation function.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Cname = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter your Course grade : ");
Grade = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter your Course weight : ");
Weight = br.readLine();
```

Many thanks, and sorry for my picky question.

Comment: take a look at [`Float.parseFloat(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)). There are similar methods for Integer, Double, Long, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to retrieve user input from the keyboard in Java is with a `Scanner`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your course name: ");
String courseName = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter your course grade: ");
float courseGrade = scanner.nextFloat();

System.out.println("Enter your course weight: ");
float courseWeight = scanner.nextFloat();

scanner.close();
```

And is there a specific reason for using `float` as opposed to `double`? If not, I'd probably just stick with double.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `scanner` method to suit each of your datatypes.

Please refer the following documentation for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html